# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.page_jsp._jspInit in Tomcat 6, but works in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

In my servlet I do:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

I get the following `NullPointerException` on Tomcat 6, but it works in Tomcat 7.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.page_jsp._jspInit(page_jsp.java:23)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:159)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at com.dotvocal.poa.vocal.main.servlet.LoadCompany.execute(MyServlet.java:100)
    at com.dotvocal.poa.vocal.main.servlet.LoadCompany.doGet(MyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I also tried the following:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/myapp/page.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: can you please provide more information about your problem ? like the full message in the log not just the "hullpointerexception" part

Comment: You will have to be more specific (i.e. full stack trace, code snippets of the lines that are causing the NullPointerException, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.page_jsp._jspInit(page_jsp.java:23)

You have servletcontainer-specific JSP libraries such as `jsp-api.jar` in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` or maybe `JDK/lib` or `JDK/lib/ext`.

**Remove** them. They don't belong there at all. The servletcontainer itself already ships with those libraries. Based on the problem symptoms, the one which you've in your webapp originated from Tomcat 7 and thus your webapp will fail to work when you deploy it to a different servletcontainer make/version such as Tomcat 6, because it would conflict with servletcontainer's own libraries.

Erroneously placing servletcontainer-specific libraries in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` is a classic starter's mistake in a wrong attempt to fix Servlet API compilation errors in the IDE project. You should instead reference the servletcontainer as "target runtime" in the IDE project.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)

Comment: removed jsp-api.jar and servlet-api.jar from /lib. Referenced the servletcontainer as "target runtime". Now it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using JBoss 4.3, my solution was deleting the log, work and tmp folder from my JBoss enviroment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?