# NullPointerException in _jspInit

Tags: java, tomcat

I got a NullPointerException in the _jspInit function in my jsp page while I access it from the web browser by typing in the address. I search the web and most of them said that this is because in my WEB-INF/lib folder, there is the .jar file jsp-api.jar confilicted with the jar file of the tomcat container like in [java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.page_jsp._jspInit in Tomcat 6, but works in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199396/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-apache-jsp-page-jsp-jspinit-in-tomcat-6). However, I check the lib folder and find no such jar files. What's the cause and how to fix it?

Here's the jsp error page:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:538)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:25)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:164)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
```

Here's my jar file list in the lib directory of my web application in tomcat6:

```
activation-1.1.jar              
antlr-2.7.6.jar                 
bean-validator.jar              
c3p0-0.9.1.jar                  
cglib-2.2.jar                   
commons-codec-1.2.jar           
commons-codec-1.4.jar           
commons-collections-3.1.jar     
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar      
commons-lang-2.4.jar            
commons-logging.jar             
commons-logging-1.1.jar         
cxf-api-2.2.9.jar               
cxf-common-schemas-2.2.9.jar    
cxf-common-utilities-2.2.9.jar  
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.2.9.jar  
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.2.9.jar   
cxf-rt-core-2.2.9.jar           
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.2.9.jar        
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.2.9.jar          
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.2.9.jar         
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.9.jar         
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.2.9.jar                 
cxf-tools-common-2.2.9.jar               
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                          
ehcache-1.2.3.jar                        
emayclient-v2.jar                        
epcis-captureclient-0.5.0.jar            
epcis-commons-0.5.0.jar                  
epcis-queryclient-0.5.0.jar              
geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar   
geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar          
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar     
geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar  
hibernate3.jar                           
httpclient-4.1.jar                       
httpcore-4.1.jar                 
httpmime-4.1.jar                 
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar           
javax.annotation.jar             
javax.ejb.jar                    
javax.enterprise.deploy.jar      
javax.jms.jar                    
javax.management.j2ee.jar        
javax.persistence.jar            
javax.resource.jar               
javax.security.auth.message.jar  
javax.security.jacc.jar          
javax.servlet.jar                
javax.servlet.jsp.jar            
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar       
javax.transaction.jar            
jaxb-api-osgi.jar                
jaxb-impl-2.2.jar                
jboss-cache-1.4.1.GA.jar                     
jbosscache-core-3.1.0.GA.jar                 
jdom-2.0.4.jar                               
jsf-api.jar                                  
jsf-impl.jar                                 
json-20090211.jar                            
jsr311-api.jar                               
jstl-impl.jar                                
jta-1.1.jar                                  
junit.jar                                    
log4j-1.2.14.jar                             
m4uapi.jar                                   
mail.jar                                     
mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar          
org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar  
oscache-2.1.jar
proxool-0.8.3.jar
qrgen-1.1.jar
saaj-api-1.3.jar
saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
swarmcache-1.0RC2.jar
textmagic-sms-api-1.0.jar
webservices-api-osgi.jar
weld-osgi-bundle.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar
zxing-core-1.7.jar
zxing-j2se-1.7.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JAR is the correct direction to go with - I would check to see if it appears in the `common.loader` property in your `catalina.properties` file (located under the `conf`) directory.

Comment: This is my common.loader line in catalina.properties:  `common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,/var/lib/tomcat6/common/classes,/var/lib/tomcat6/common/*.jar`. Do you mean that the missing or conflicted jar file is just jsp-api.jar, or there is some other jar file went wrong?

Comment: Your `common.loader` configuration seems like the default - so assuming you validated all the jars in your classpath and found no collision - this might not be the direction to proceed your investigation with.

Comment: There is one line in the log file: `Jan 8, 2013 10:40:41 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/SCMPUSH2/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class Jan 8, 2013 10:40:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory`. Will it be related to the problem?

Comment: It looks like the `javax.servlet.Servlet` class appears twice in your JVM configuration - this might indicate that the wrong one was loaded.

Search all your JARs to see which one contains this class - and then remove it from the classpath.

Note - this is just a guess

Comment: I've change my tomcat version from 6 to 7 and the error doesn't occur, while all the warnings during startup have all been shown up as before. Since my tomcat6 could work in some time before and came down suddenly after which it can never go back, I may not say that the problem is fixed. I just hope that maybe tomcat7 will solve this issue. However I still want to know why is this ...